# Avoid "The OutputPath property is not set for project" by specifying default build config

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a situation similar to the following:

A solution with two projects, **A** and **B**, with **A** referencing **B**.  In addition to the standard build configs, `Debug` and `Release`, I would like to add a third `Staging`, which lets me do some config transforms for project **A** only.  The `Staging` build config would have no effect on **B** and so I don't add it to the project.

Using the solution configuration manager, it's easy to set this scenario up...when the Active Configuration is `Staging`, **A** will use `Staging` and **B** will use `Debug`.  The solution builds as expected.  However, running

```
msbuild A.csproj /p:Configuration=Staging
```

will fail with `The OutputPath property is not set for project B` since B does not have the `Staging` build config.

My question is if there is a simple way to avoid this when building the project via `msbuild`

Adding the `Staging` config to **B** would work, but it seems cleaner to only add build configs to the projects they affect, and leave the rest alone.  In a solution with many projects, ensuring every project has all of the possible build configs is not ideal (though not exactly terrible, either).

Answer (score 0):

In the A.csproj file add the following lines

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ConfigList Condition=" '@(ConfigList)' == '' and $(Config) != '' " Include="$(Config.Split('+'))" />
    <!-- parse all requested configurations into a list -->
    <ConfigList Condition=" '@(ConfigList)' == '' " Include="Debug" />
    <!-- if no configurations were specified, default to Debug -->
  </ItemGroup>
```

And add a target for the referenced project in A.csproj

```
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\B\B.csproj" Properties="Configuration=%(ConfigList.Identity);OutputPath=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\%(ConfigList.Identity)" Targets="Build" />
  </Target>
```

When you build the project A, using /p:Configuration=Staging, the target to the referenced project will pass the configuration along and create the output directory required.

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511274/using-msbuild-to-build-multiple-configurations), it gives a clear description of what you are trying to do.