# How to build csproj which has other dependent projects with some predefined configuration

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I have 4 dependent projects (`.csproj`) which need to be build first before this current project is built. I want to build dependent projects with some different configurations.

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Database\Database.csproj">
      <Project>{1b760081-dd0b-4515-bebb-8495cb5edfa7}</Project>
      <Name>Database</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Common\Common.csproj">
      <Project>{14966c67-c28f-4db3-9e6c-f647236ecd34}</Project>
      <Name>Common</Name>
```

suppose i want to build database with prod-india.config and similarly common with prod-china.config how to do so
i am using msbuild to exe to build it where i am passing the csporj of the main file along with the configuratuon

Comment: no i dont think so.. i dont care about the order i just want to build them with some configuration let say debug|AnyCpu...

Comment: Perhaps this one? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511274/using-msbuild-to-build-multiple-configurations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MSBuild to Build Multiple Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511274/using-msbuild-to-build-multiple-configurations)

Comment: any more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can override some msbuild properties directly in the project reference:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Database\Database.csproj">
  <Project>{1b760081-dd0b-4515-bebb-8495cb5edfa7}</Project>
  <Name>Database</Name>
  <AdditionalProperties>Configuration=SomethingCustom</AdditionalProperties>
</ProjectReference>
```